# Does the command mysqldump generate the dump locally before transferring?

Tags: mysql

I need to get a mysqldump from a remote server database.

The server is quite old and the space left is little.

There is for now 15 GB left of free space but the database backup will be more than 25 GB (it is a client's server, I cannot free any space).

So my question is: when I will try the following command on my Windows:

```
mysqldump -h remoteserverhost -u username -p database > C:\path\data.sql
```

Will it be a risk to saturate the server or the data will be transferred directly? I am afraid this command will try to generate the full dump on the remote server before transferring it.

Comment: I'm duphammering this good question, because the the *answer* in the duplicate is relevant, even though the question is different.

Comment: @O.Jones Thanks for the feedback, indeed it seems the option --quick is the answer, I'll try it soon. I have a question for you though, what does "duphammering" mean? Thanks!